# Buffer function crashing QGIS only on specific data set

Tags: qgis, buffer, minidump

I'm trying to run the buffer tool on a line and it keeps crashing Qgis.  The line is created by merging two sets of gps point data and running points to lines with  gps_date as the order. I have no problem with it working on other data sets but for some reason there are two data sets that cause the buffer to crash the program. Any idea on what would cause this?

The data doesn't look corrupted and Qgis is outputting a .dmp file but I don't understand what it's indicating.

Comment: No oddities like the line doubling back on itself, or crossing?

Comment: @mkennedy Oh yeah, it crosses itself multiple times but the other data I've processed does the same thing.

Comment: It could be you've managed to find a case that the buffer algorithm can't handle. You might try chopping it up into a few pieces and see if you can isolate the problem section.

Comment: If the issue is reproducible with the dataset, this should probably be a bug report on https://issues.qgis.org/issues. Make sure you provide the dataset so devs can try to reproduce and test the issue

Comment: @underdark  Thanks, I put one up.  In the meantime I guess I'll keep hacking away at it till I find what's crashing it.